# Increase time by milliseconds in Excel

Tags: excel, time

I have a certain value of time(10:00:00:00) and I have 1000 samples in excel for one minuit till 
(10:00:01:00) which means every time interval to every sample is 0.06 second.

How could add 0.06 second to 10:00:00:00 incrementally  till reach to 10:00:01:00  in excel

```
10:00:00:00 AM
10:00:00:06
10:00:00:12
10:00:00:18
:
: 
10:00:59:54
10:00:01:00
```

**hint:** I need the formula of time in milliseconds due to big data samples for 24 hours and every hour has 1000 samples which means 24000 samples.

Comment: I would not use Excel's time representation at all - just store the millisecond count as an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that:

Cell A1 contains start time: 10:00:00.00 AM

Cell Z1 contains constant: 00:00.06

Cell A2 will be: =A1+$Z$1

Then you can drag down A2...